# Magento Configurable Product Disable Dropdown if Out of Stocks

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

There is 2 attribute on my configurable product (Size and Color)

I want to disable option on dropdown (Size or Color) if there is a out of stock product.It should be seen as gray and disable.

How can I do?

Magento ver. 1.9.2.1

Comment: can you please paste your `view.phtml` file code here ?

Answer (score 0):

**First you get out  configurable product  have  out of stock child product by below code and set a flag;**

```
$hasOutofStock=false;
$allProducts = Mage::registry('current_product')->getTypeInstance(true)
    ->getUsedProducts(null, Mage::registry('current_product'));

foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
    /* Check  child product is not for sales or out of stock*/        
    if (!$product->isSaleable()) {
        $hasOutofStock=true;
        break;
    }
}
```

***Then use of this flag  and with help js disable drop down.***

```
<?php if ($hasOutofStock == true): ?>
<script>
    jQuery(".product-options-wrapper select).prop('disabled',true);
</script>
<?php endif: ?>
```

Comment: thank you for answered . can you tell me where those file directory?

Comment: just goto `app/design/frontend/[your_Package]/[Your_Theme]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

Comment: I tried but didn't work :/

Comment: @Anyone Help :: after selecting drop-down value the price going to "0", how can I solve the issue?